# Multipeer Connectivity: why connecting to Peer sometimes fails?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

When i send an invite and the other side accepts, the remote peer changes state to connecting, but then SOMETIMES to ('not connected')

```
Peer [Peter’s MacBook Air] changed state to Connecting
Peer [Peter’s MacBook Air] changed state to Not Connected
```

I understand that the Multipeer Connectivity hides much from the developer, but a reason would be at least nice as the connection sometimes works and sometimes not (the problem is not in the code)

The devices are next to each other, both WiFi and BT connected

Our application depends on Multipper and issues like this can mean lost customers...What can be done to improve connectivity on Multipeer

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to connect peers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I wish someone could shed some light...

Comment: I am also experiencing same

Comment: Hello, may I ask how did you fix this issue? Thanks in advance @ChrisH

Comment: I have the same issue as well, @ChrisH, do you have a solution?

Comment: let's hope that iOS10 will improve the Multipeer Connectivity